# converting ruby struct to yaml

Tags: struct, yaml

I have a struct in ruby that looks like this:

```
Struct.new("Device", :brand, :model, :port_id)
@devices = [
 Struct::Device.new('Apple', 'iphone5', 3),
 Struct::Device.new('Samsung', 'Galaxy S4', 1)
]
```

Converting this to_yaml gives me this result:

```
---
- !ruby/struct:Struct::Device
  brand: Apple
  model: iphone5
  port_id: 3
- !ruby/struct:Struct::Device
  brand: Samsung
  model: Galaxy S4
  port_id: 1
```

However I'm still not sure how to convert my struct back from yaml whenever I need to use it in my code. When I add `devices:` on top of the yaml code and then try to parse it back to ruby struct from the CONFIG['devices'] variable - I don't get any results.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing your problem:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Struct.new("Device", :brand, :model, :port_id)
=> Struct::Device
irb(main):003:0> devices = [
irb(main):004:1*  Struct::Device.new('Apple', 'iphone5', 3),
irb(main):005:1*  Struct::Device.new('Samsung', 'Galaxy S4', 1)
irb(main):006:1> ]
=> [#<struct Struct::Device brand="Apple", model="iphone5", port_id=3>, #<struct Struct::Device brand="Samsung", model="Galaxy S4", port_id=1>]
irb(main):007:0> y = devices.to_yaml
=> "---\n- !ruby/struct:Struct::Device\n  brand: Apple\n  model: iphone5\n  port_id: 3\n- !ruby/struct:Struct::Device\n  brand: Samsung\n  model: Galaxy S4\n  port_id: 1\n"
irb(main):008:0> obj = YAML::load(y)
=> [#<struct Struct::Device brand="Apple", model="iphone5", port_id=3>, #<struct Struct::Device brand="Samsung", model="Galaxy S4", port_id=1>]
```

You must make sure that the `Struct.new` runs before the `YAML::load` as well as before the `.to_yaml`. Otherwise Ruby doesn't know how to create the struct from text.

Okay, as I said, you must run the Struct definition before trying to load.  Plus you are trying to build a hash, so use that YAML syntax:

`config.yml`:

```
---
devices:
- !ruby/struct:Struct::Device
  brand: Apple
  model: iphone5
  port_id: 3
- !ruby/struct:Struct::Device
  brand: Samsung
  model: Galaxy S4
  port_id: 1
```

And `test.rb`:

```
require 'yaml' 
Struct.new("Device", :brand, :model, :port_id)
CONFIG = YAML::load_file('./config.yml') unless defined? CONFIG 
devices = CONFIG['devices']
puts devices.inspect
```

Result:

```
C:\>ruby test.rb
[#<struct Struct::Device brand="Apple", model="iphone5", port_id=3>, #<struct Struct::Device brand="Samsung", model="Galaxy S4", port_id=1>]
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess my question is more like this:
If I initially have the struct in yaml format in my config.yml file how do I correctly read it?

The way I have it now is like this:

config.yml
`devices:
- !ruby/struct:Struct::Device
  brand: Apple
  model: iphone5
  port_id: 3
- !ruby/struct:Struct::Device
  brand: Samsung
  model: Galaxy S4
  port_id: 1`

test.rb
`require 'yaml'
CONFIG = YAML.load_file('./config.yml') unless defined? CONFIG
devices = CONFIG['devices']

and then when I do `puts devices` I can't get any results.

Comment: @user2175891 You should read the answer! You were missing the `Struct` definition.   This is needed before you try to load.  Also a minor problem with the YAML. See my additional code.

Comment: @user2175891 It would be good to accept the answer if it was helpful.